# Is it fine to use pure PhP/MySql queries in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Wordpress uses it's own version of php and queries data in its own way.
Would it be a bad technique to use WP with pure mySQL commands like "SELECT * FROM * WHERE blablabla"?

Comment: its fine if you are firing the queries using `$wpdb` object...  wordpress database class reference can be found here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the sql queries but you need to follow the Wordpress standard for this.You must use global $wpdb variable for connection.
Please check the link for further select queries examples.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use pure PHP/MySQL to customize Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gone through codex there is [wpdb class reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) you are getting example of almost all basic queries their and it is object oriented, so it is better to follow codex and use wpdb class, beside this, if you are thinking to connect to database with custom code and want to use raw MySql queries, I will discourage you, as it is not needed and make your code look little dirty while use wpdb will keep your code cleaner.

About the query you have mentioned using wpdb too you will write queries sometimes raw and sometimes with function calls which is going to generate queries at last but will maintain a style that will keep things clean and simple.